# Proper and free action of a discrete group

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, compactness, smooth-manifolds

In Gallot, Hulin, Lafontaine's *Riemannian Geometry*:

> **Definition** Let $G$ be a discrete group, acting continuously on the left on a locally compact topological space $E$. One says that $G$ acts *properly* on $E$ if, for $x,y\in E$ where $y$ does not belong to the orbit of $x$ under $G$, there exist two neighborhoods $V$ and $W$ of $x$ and $y$ respectively such that, for any $g\in G$, $gV\cap W=\emptyset$ holds. The group $G$ acts *freely* if, for $x\in M$ and $g\in G$ with $g\neq\operatorname{id}$, then $gx\neq x$.

Now in the proof of the following theorem

> **Theorem** Let $G$ be a discrete group of diffeomorphisms of a manifold $M$. If $G$ acts properly and freely on $M$, there exists on the topological quotient space $M/G$ a unique structure of smooth manifold such that the canonical projection $\pi\colon M\to M/G$ is a covering map.

it's claimed that

> Moreover, since $G$ acts freely, every $x$ in $M$ is contained in an open set $U$ such that all the open sets $gU$ are pairwise disjoint when $g$ runs through $G$.

I cannot see the reason for this, according to the prior definitions. As far as I've searched on the Internet or books, usually the condition is assumed in the definition of a proper action, so I don't know whether this is implied in the preceding definitions. I wonder how to prove this.

Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The definition of proper you quote is not the standard definition, and it is not strong enough to imply this result. Consider the following example: Let $G = S^1$ act on $M = \mathbb{R}^2\smallsetminus\{(0,0)\}$ in the usual way, i.e. by rotations about the origin. This action is clearly free. However, equip $G$ with the discrete topology. Note that this makes the topology on $G$ finer, so the action map $G\times M\to M$ is still continuous (the preimages of open sets were open using the usually topology on $G$, so by making the topology strictly finer, they are still open).

Now, I claim that this action satisfies the definition of proper you state in the first quote. Pick $x$, and then the orbit of $x$ is the circle about the origin of radius $\|x\|$. Pick $y$ not in the orbit of $x$ (so $\|x\|\neq\|y\|$), let $\epsilon = |\|x\| - \|y \||$, and let $V$ and $W$ be the $\epsilon/2$ balls about $x$ and $y$, respectively. It is easy to see that $gV\cap W = \emptyset$ for each $g \in G$, as $gV$ is contained in the "$\epsilon/2$-annulus" about the orbit of $x$, while $W$ doesn't intersect this annulus.

However, obviously, there is no open neighborhood $U$ of any $x$ such that the $gU$ are pairwise disjoint. In fact, for each $x\in M$, any open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ intersects the orbit $Gx$ at infinitely many points.

I'll also mention that the quoted definition of proper doesn't imply many of the other important consequences of proper actions. Proper actions of discrete groups (by the standard definition) have finite stabilizers. But consider the example of $\mathbb{Z}$ acting trivially on a point; it satisfies the quoted definition vacuously (only one orbit), but the stabilizer of the point is $\mathbb{Z}$. Similarly, proper actions by the usual definition have Hausdorff quotients (distinct orbits can be separated by open sets)--in my opinion, this is the the main reason for restricting to proper actions (at least for many purposes). However, the example [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Properly_discontinuous_action#Wandering_actions) satisfies the quoted definition, but the orbits of $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ contain arbitrarily close points, as explained at that page.

I'm not familiar with the book you are using, but it sounds like they intended the standard definition: the map $G\times M \to M\times M$ given by $(g,x)\mapsto (x,gx)$ is a proper map, i.e. a closed map such that the preimage of each compact set is compact. [tom Dieck's *Transformation Groups*](http://books.google.com/books/about/Transformation_Groups.html?id=azcQhi6XeioC) gives a pretty nice treatment of this definition and its consequences in a general setting starting on page 27.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It seems that Lee's book on smooth manifolds also takes this as definition.

Comment: You mean Lee's book uses the definition in terms of $G\times M\to M \times M$, right? Also, see Lemma 9.17 in Lee's book, where an equivalent characterization is given for discrete groups (related to the condition in your question).

Comment: Lest anyone get confused, Lemma 9.17 that @cws referred to is in the first edition of my smooth manifolds book. In the second edition, there's an analogous (but slightly different) result in Lemma 21.11.