# Free cocompact action of discrete group gives a covering map

Tags: algebraic-topology, group-theory, general-topology

I'd like to find a short proof of the following seemingly basic fact encountered on the second page of Atiyah's paper "Elliptic operators, discrete groups, and von Neumann algebras." http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/atiyah_elld.pdf

Suppose a discrete group $G$ acts freely on a manifold $X$ with the quotient $X/G$ being compact. Then $X$ is a covering space of $X/G$ with covering map given by the quotient map $p: X\rightarrow X/G$.

Thanks.

Comment: To the downvoter: it would be appreciated when you downvote an answer if you could provide an explanation for the downvote. Even better, if you thought the question is too trivial, it would be nice if you could provide a quick answer and move it to StackExchange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The discreteness assumption is meaningless since given a continuous group action $G\times X\to X$, it remains continuous if we equip $G$ with discrete topology. Now, a counter-example to the claim is the action of the group of the additive group of real numbers on itself 
$$
{\mathbb R}_{d} \times {\mathbb R} \to {\mathbb R}
$$
via addition. Here the subscript $d$ means the discrete topology, otherwise ${\mathbb R}$ is equipped with the standard topology. The quotient space is a single point, hence, compact. The action itself is clearly not a covering action, but is free. I think, Atiyah forgot to add  **proper**, in the sense of Palais:

A continuous action $G\times X\to X$ is **proper**, in the sense of Palais, if for any two points $x, y\in X$ there exists a pair of neighborhoods $U_x, U_y$ of these points such that
$$
\{g\in G: g U_x\cap U_y\ne \emptyset\} 
$$
is a relatively compact subset of $G$. When $G$ is discrete, this just means that this subset is finite.

The correct statement is then:

If $G\times X\to X$ is a Palais-proper, free, action of a discrete group on a Hausdorff space, then the projection X\to X/G$ is a covering map.

Related: [Proper and free action of a discrete group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/989999/proper-and-free-action-of-a-discrete-group?rq=1).

Comment: In certain contexts the discreteness assumption might have some meaning. For instance, in the link provided, in the special context of the 3rd and 4th pages, $\Gamma$ is a discrete subgroup of the Lie group $G = SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ acting transitively on the upper half plane $X$. In that situation, discreteness of $\Gamma$ in $G$ implies proper discontinuity or Palais-properness of the $\Gamma$ action on $X$. The extra feature of this special context, used to verify properness of $\Gamma$, is that the stabilizer of a point of $X$ under the action of $G$ on $X$ is a compact subgroup of $G$.

Comment: @Lee Mosher: Yes, of course, except this is not what OP was asking. I guess the course of the problem is two notions of discreteness, of an abstract group and of a subgroup of a topological group. Atiyah I am sure meant the latter.

Answer (score 1):

[Dave Glickenstein's notes](http://math.arizona.edu/~glickenstein/math534_1011/coveringspaces.pdf) give a short proof, see page 9.

Comment: Do you mind pointing out which proposition this is? I see Remark 5 on page 10 being the closest statement, but this assumes that the action is properly discontinuous, which is not assumed in my question.