# The covering space of CW-complex from free action

Tags: algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

Let discrete group $G$ act on CW-complex $X$ freely and cocompactly by permuting $X$'s cells. Then is $X\to X/G$ always a covering space or is there a counter example?

Comment: Yes, it is a covering space. See here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1769384/free-cocompact-action-of-discrete-group-gives-a-covering-map

Comment: @Mathematics But there it added proper, and my question doesn't require proper. Also here we have some stronger properties like $G$ acts by permuting $X$'s cells